# Unable to install Android NDK Application on Android x86 Tablet

Tags: android, x86, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I am having a ViewSonic Tablet Intel Atom processor running with Android OS. I have created a helloWorld App using Android SDk, I am able to run on my tablet but when I tried my actual app with have JNI interface too, the application installation failed with an error message "Application not Installed".

Can some one guide me how I can install (or compile) my application (including JNI layer) so that It can run on my Android Tablet.

Do I need to compile my JNI libs using [android-x86 NDK](http://www.android-x86.org/) or normal NDK is fine?

-Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x86 is not supported in the current release of the NDK

> The latest release of the NDK supports
>   these ARM instruction sets:
>
> - ARMv5TE (including Thumb-1
>     instructions)
> - ARMv7-A (including
>     Thumb-2 and VFPv3-D16 instructions,
>     with optional support for
>     NEON/VFPv3-D32 instructions)
>
> Future releases of the NDK will also support:
>
> - x86 instructions (see
>     CPU-ARCH-ABIS.HTML for more
>     information)

[Source: Google NDK Documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html)

Comment: what about using android-x86 NDK?

Comment: Try it. I never had the need, since I develop for phones where all phones are ARM based not x86... It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check again... Latest version of Android NDK (r6b or later) supports x86.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/ndk-for-ia/#building-ndk-applications
http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

To build the native library for x86, you must append x86 in the APP_ABI variable

File: **./jni/Application.mk**

**APP_ABI** := armeabi armeabi-v7a **x86**
APP_PLATFORM := android-8

Or just set "all", to build for all platforms supported by the NDK (armeabi armeabi-v7a mips x86)

**APP_ABI** := **all**
APP_PLATFORM := android-8

In my case I use android-ndk-r9b